# Difference between System account and Farm admin account

Tags: farm-admin, system-account

I am quite new to SharePoint. I am confused between System account and Farm admin account.
Could you please explain difference between these two.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Farm Account: This account is also referred to as the database access
>   account. This account has the following properties:
>
> It's the application pool identity for the SharePoint Central
>   Administration website. It's the process account for the Windows
>   SharePoint Services Timer service.
>
> System Account: System account is the same account used by application
>   pool of your SharePoint web application in IIS at the time of
>   creation/extension of respective web application.

Comment: Thank You Nadeem for the reply. Do you mean to say that System Account is used by application pool of the SharePoint Web Application and Farm is used by application pool of SharePoint Central Administration website?
Kindly share more difference. Thank you!

Comment: Yes that is correct, Farm account is also used by SharePoint timer service.